# Deallocate objects for all class from a controller when view disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to deallocate all objects created in a view controller when the view disappear

Now my code is

-(void) viewdiddisappear

{

[super dealloc];

}

this is not working

Thanks in advance,

Comment: see this link it helps http://blog.harbinger-systems.com/2014/04/ios-memory-management-and-arc/

Comment: Are you using ARC? If so, no need to call dealloc. They should automatically get released when out of scope. If you allocated any custom objects, try implementing -(void)dealloc and doing any cleanup there.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Got it ... Thanks

Comment: @Jayasabeen -- welcome bro,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here code with right direction:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    if (self.view.window == nil) //you should be sure what the view is removed from the window
    {
        self.view = nil;
        //remove other temporary objects
        //self.models = nil;
        //[self.request cancel];
    }
}
```

You'll restore objects in - (void)viewDidLoad method. 
Generally you can't destroy a viewController if the view is disappeared from the screen, because a instance of UINavigationViewController can hold a reference or other container.
And never call dealloc method from any methods with exception -(void)dealloc method. You can (should) call dealloc method by hand only if you manage memory pull by hand.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in ARC environment, then you don't even need to call dealloc method. However, if you really want to free up objects then you can implement dealloc method without  `[super dealloc];`  call.

```
- (void) dealloc {
    someObject = nil;
    otherObject.delegate = nil;
    otherObject = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Help to this code:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    if (self.view.window == nil)
    {
        self.view = nil;
        someObject = nil;
        otherObject.delegate = nil;
        otherObject = nil;

    }
}
```